# How to determine which topology a BJT is configured to from a given circuit diagram?

Tags: transistors, bjt, diagram

As far as I understand, a BJT in *any* given circuit must fall in exactly one of the following configurations:

-Common emitter.

-Common collector.

-Common base.

So my question is:

1. Are there any other configurations a BJT can be in? Are these 3 configurations the only possibilities for a BJT to be in?
2. How can I determine which configuration a BJT is configured to from a given circuit diagram?

Comment: at 2: In general: while looking at the circuit, which pin is grounded or will have the lowest signal amplitude: that is the common pin. Practice this while looking at circuits and it will soon become clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The three basic configurations (CE, CC, CB) don't cover all possibilities but they are essential to quickly determine the behavior of a circuit.

The configuration is always determined with respect to a given input and given output and therefore depends on the signal path that is being analyzed.

The determination of the type of configuration is actually quite simple. The name of the topology is determined by the node which is at AC ground, that is the node that carries no signal.

We have to start by identifying the input and the output of the single transistor circuit, which already excludes two terminals. The remaining terminal determines the name of the configuration.

For example a CE configuration has the input at the base (we exclude the base), the output at the collector (we exclude the collector), so that only the emitter remains. Hence, we have a CE configuration.

Might sound like a strange approach but works very well.

Comment: Wow, this answer has clarified quite a bit. Thanks. But now I have 2 questions: 1) What if the input is at the collector and output is at the base? Or is such thing possible? 2) The "input" and "output" are totally about how we perceive the signals right? That is: Do we state that this signal is our input and that signal is our output?

Comment: Input and output always depend on the point of view and the behavior we want to analyze. We could ask ourselves how well an amplifier isolates the input from the output and then we would inject a signal into the collector and look at the signal we get at the base. Why not?

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any other configurations a BJT can be in?

A differential pair has each transistor simultaneously in both common base and common emitter and sometimes one of these two transistors will be in common collector: -

[image]

R2 helps fine tune the performance but can be a short circuit hence T2 is kind of in all three circuit topologies.

Some circuits have an output from both collector and emitter when producing an in-phase (emitter) signal and an inverted signal (collector) for feeding some types of output transistors in audio amplifiers. What category would you put these in?

[image]

> How can I determine which configuration a BJT is configured to from a
>   given circuit diagram?

Not important - maybe an analogy is what the firing order is for a 4 cylinder engine. That is detail that is useful but doesn't take anything away from recognizing many more important topological things about the engine used.

Comment: "What category would you put these in?" Actually, I have no idea. I am just trying to understand how BJTs work in general. Since these 3 configurations have well defined properties respectively, I thought that had any configuration been exclusive to others, and if I could determine which configuration a BJT is in, I could understand the function of a given circuit.

Comment: But, let's say for the differential pair: Are the transistors in both common base and common emitter configurations _at a time instance_ as well? That is: If I look at the snapshot of the circuit at a given time, would I be able to say "this transistor is in this configuration, the other one is in that configuration etc." or would they still be both common base and common emitter at this time instance? (Sorry if this is a bad question, I am just seeing that circuit for the first time and hence I don't have any idea how it works.)

Comment: For a diff pair each transistor is simultaneously receiving a signal at the emitter (common base) and a signal at the base (common emitter). If it were not so this type of differential amplifier would not work.